# How to make inline elements APPEAR inline inside of a flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>title</span>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want title to appear in the middle of the screen, as old inline element. But inside a flex container, it's expanded like block-level elements.

What am I missing here?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rk5h5ph7/

Comment: Add `align-items: center;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t fully understand what you want, but try one of what I’ve suggested.

Try to add this to `.container span`:

```
text-align: center;
```

or add this to `.container`:

```
align-items: center;
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace justify-content with align-itmes

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.container span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>title</span>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```